# Which trick to use here $\sqrt[n]{n}\le1+\sqrt{\frac 2n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

> Which trick to use here $\sqrt[n]{n}\le1+\sqrt{\frac 2n}$, with $n$ natural number

Writing it as a function and considering the derivative didn't bring anything, Right side decreases faster, there must be more elementary proof, can you help ?

Comment: what is $n$ here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n = 1$, the inequality is easy to see. For $n \ge 2$, note that your inequality is equivalent to
$$n \le \left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}\right)^n.$$

Expanding the term on the RHS using the binomial theorem yields the assertion
$$\left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}\right)^n = 1 + \binom{n}{1} \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} + \binom{n}{2} \frac{2}{n} + \ldots \ge 1 + \frac{n(n - 1)}{2} \frac{2}{n} = n.$$